# Why can't python's datetime.max survive a round trip through timestamp / fromtimestamp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

In most cases I can round-trip datetimes to and from a timestamp as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime(2016, 1, 1, 12, 34, 56, 789)
print(dt)
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(dt.timestamp()))
```

> 2016-01-01 12:34:56.000789
>
> 2016-01-01 12:34:56.000789

But this doesn't work for datetime.max. Why is that?

```
dt = datetime.max
print(dt)
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(dt.timestamp()))
```

> 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "python", line 9, in  ValueError: year is out of range

More precisely, why hasn't the datetime library taken this case into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because the maximum of a datetime object is not the same as the maximum of a valid timestamp.

There's also a good reason to limit the range of timestamps: they are but a simple python `float`, which, on "normal" machines are double precision floating points. But: you lose more than a couple of seconds in precision:

```
print(datetime.max.timestamp())
253402297200.0
print(datetime.max.second)
59
print(datetime.max.microsecond)
999999
```

**spot the error.**

Timestamps based on floating point numbers are, *by definition* less accurate the more they are in the future. So not being able to represent arbitrary valid `datetimes` in a timestamp is perfectly reasonable, just as restricting one a couple thousand years in the future.

so:

> More precisely, why hasn't the datetime library taken this case into account?

Because timestamps so far in the future are unreliably and very likely do not represent the time you've meant, so rejecting them is a wise thing.

Takeaway: a floating point number like `timestamp()` produces is not an appropriate way of transporting times with fixed precision. If you at all can, avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

```
dt = datetime.max
```

is checking against the maximum of the datetime class. It is a static value.

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(dt.timestamp()))
```

This, however, is working against a timestamp. Different classes, different methods. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.max) are the docs for datetime's methods.